# Conversion between RYB and RGB color spaces for RYYB images

Tags: math, image-processing, colors

I'm working on the project where I need to convert RYB color scheme to RGB, but we use raw images from Sony IMX600y / IMX650 sensor with Quad RYYB pattern where black level is 240 and white level is 2^12-1.

I've read and implemented this algorithm [Paint Inspired Color Mixing and Compositing for Visualization](http://vis.computer.org/vis2004/DVD/infovis/papers/gossett.pdf) and [On the Transfer of Painting Style to Photographic Images through Attention to
Colour Contrast](http://opticalenquiry.com/files/Zhang_TRANSFER.pdf), but can't figure out how to apply it to Bayer images.

If I use [bilinear demosaicing algorithm](https://colour-demosaicing.readthedocs.io/en/develop/_modules/colour_demosaicing/bayer/demosaicing/bilinear.html#demosaicing_CFA_Bayer_bilinear) (from colour_demosaicing lib) and then use my implementation of conversion algorithm from page above (or [js implementation](https://github.com/bahamas10/node-ryb2rgb/blob/master/ryb2rgb.js) that gives the same result)

```py
import numpy as np
from colour_demosaicing import demosaicing_CFA_Bayer_bilinear

def ryb2rgb(ryb):
    ...

raw = np.fromfile('img.raw', dtype=np.int16).reshape(5472, 7296)
ryb = np.clip(demosaicing_CFA_Bayer_bilinear((raw-240)/(2**12-1-240), 'RGGB'), 0, 1)

rgb = ryb2rgb(ryb)
```

then I get:

[image: rgb]

where is my mistake?

Any help is appreciated.
Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is confusing and what you are asking is weird. There are no RYYB nor RGGB color spaces, but RYB and RGB. Then RGGB can indeed be used to describe one of the possible pattern arrangement in a Bayer mosaic format. But I never heard of a Bayer mosaic based on the RYB model (by the way completely inexistent in the computer graphics/image processing universes). In fact, no device that I know is able to display or capture images using this model. In the printing industry, CMY/CMYK are much more common. The acronym RYYB does not appear in the linked papers.

This said, you can find the conversion formulas in "Computational RYB Color Model and its Applications, Sugita & Takahashi".

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I fixed the question. We use cameras with Sony imx650 sensor with Quad RYYB filter.

Comment: Better lookup the Sony datasheet.